# Trigger a vanilla js click event at specific coordinates for ie11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, triggers

I watnted to trigger a JavaScript 'click' event at specific coords for ie. So far I've got this:

```
var myelem = document.getElementById('elem');
var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e.initEvent('click', true, false, null, 0,0,0, 10, 10);

myelem.dispatchEvent(e);
```

It works on e.g. buttons but as soon as I try to specify coordinates none are used for the trigger (clienX and clientY value equals 0). I've noticed that 'MouseEvent' clientX and clientY attr [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event) are specified as 'readonly'.

Is there a way to trigger the event with proper coords on an element in ie11?